# Can the format of a timestamp in an org-mode document be locally adjusted for export?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have an `org` document:

```
#+Title: Birthdays of The Beatles

John Lennon was born on <1940-10-09 Mon>.

Each member of the Beatles had a birthday.

| Beatle          | Birthday         |
|-----------------+------------------|
| John Lennon     | <1940-10-09 Mon> |
| Paul McCartney  | <1942-06-18 Thu> |
| George Harrison | <1943-02-25 Thu> |
| Ringo Starr     | <1940-07-07 Sun> |
```

which exports to ascii as

```
               __________________________

            BIRTHDAYS OF THE BEATLES

                   Me
               __________________________


John Lennon was born on <1940-10-09 Wed>.

Each member of the Beatles had a birthday.

 Beatle           Birthday         
-----------------------------------
 John Lennon      <1940-10-09 Wed> 
 Paul McCartney   <1942-06-18 Thu> 
 George Harrison  <1943-02-25 Thu> 
 Ringo Starr      <1940-07-07 Sun>
```

I want to alter the formats of the dates so that the dates in the body and the dates in the table are different:

```
               __________________________

            BIRTHDAYS OF THE BEATLES

                   Me
               __________________________


John Lennon was born on <Wed Oct-09 1940>.

Each member of the Beatles had a birthday.

 Beatle           Birthday         
-----------------------------------
 John Lennon      <Oct-09>
 Paul McCartney   <Jun-18>
 George Harrison  <Feb-25>
 Ringo Starr      <Jul-07>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

What happens to timestamps when you export to ASCII is determined by the function `org-ascii-timestamp` (likewise `org-latex-timestamp` for Latex export and so on).  You just have to redefine that to make them export to whatever you like.  Here we use `org-read-date` to convert the timestamp to an internal time and `format-time-string` to format the time in whatever way we like:

```
(defun org-ascii-timestamp (timestamp _contents info)
  (format-time-string
   "<%b-%d>"
   (org-read-date nil t (org-timestamp-translate timestamp))))
```

Unfortunately, this will alter the timestamps for /all/ ASCII exports, not just this document.  To make it truly document local, you would have to redefine the export function to something like

```
(defun org-ascii-timestamp (timestamp contents info)
    (funcall org-ascii-timestamp-function (timestamp contents info))
```

and set `org-ascii-timestamp-function` to be a function with the current definition of `org-ascii-timestamp`.  Then you could use `#+BIND` to change the definition locally.  This is a bit of a hack and also affects the whole document.

What we really want is to set a property (say `TIMESTAMP_FMT`) and have it apply only to that subtree.  It is somewhat difficult to lookup properties during export, but it can be done:

```
(defvar org-ascii-timestamp-format "<%Y-%m-%d %a>")

(defun org-ascii-timestamp (timestamp _contents info)
  (let ((org-ascii-timestamp-format
         (or (org-entry-get (plist-get (car (cdr timestamp)) :begin)
                            "TIMESTAMP_FMT")
             org-ascii-timestamp-format)))
    (format-time-string
     org-ascii-timestamp-format
     (org-read-date nil t (org-timestamp-translate timestamp)))))
```

This makes the timestamp format local to a tree (it can be inherited or not depending on how you set `org-use-property-inheritance`).  I don't know a way to make a property local to a table.

Comment: Wouldn't that change the timestamp in the text as well as the ones in the table?

Comment: Also in "modern" org-mode (>=9.0) the `org-timestamp-translate` function uses the variable `org-time-stamp-custom-formats`, so you don't have to redefine the `org-ascii-timestamp` function; just the variable (I think, but I did not test). But it still would affect both the text and table timestamps.

Comment: Yes changing the function changes it everywhere.  I've added in a function that changes it in just a subtree.

Comment: @Nick I hadn't been aware of `org-time-stamp-custom-formats`.  It almost does the right thing, but I don't see a way of modifying it locally short of redefining the function as above.